# Ads are missing in my project after upgrading to xcode7

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm not getting ads in my app after upgrade it to xcode7 and running it on ios9 device,i'm not getting any errors any one knows please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you trying the app in the simulator or on your actual device? The device would be much better to check for real ads

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with iOS9's addition of NSAppTransportSecurity requiring https:// connections versus http://.

Because of the same issue Facebook Audience Network ads have also stopped working on iOS9. Facebook now requires you to [white list their servers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9) for network requests to fix the issue. I think the same issue with iAd, and the solution should  be similar.